# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object, not sure where it is coming from

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a bit rusty so apologies in advance if this is something simple. My code does not work because of "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" at this part:

```
def main():
    tick, status = get_tick()
    ticker_list = ['UB','GEM','ETF']
    market_prices = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
    market_prices = market_prices.reshape(3,2)`
```

If someone could give me some pointers/how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated! This is a code to trade stocks based on the tickers in the list above.

I understand that some kind of object is not found so it is returning None but how is that the case if all the things above are clearly there and stated

This is the get_tick() function

```
def get_tick():   
    resp = s.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/case')
    if resp.ok:
        case = resp.json()
        return case['tick'], case['status']
```

Comment: The error is saying that you are trying to unpack a non-iterable. Assuming that the numpy functions aren't causing it from an inner method since it seems unlikely, in this case that would be `tick, status = get_tick()`. The error further says `non-iterable NoneType object`, meaning that `get_tick()` is returning `None`. Check your `get_tick()` function.

Comment: `get_tick()` may well not be using a return expression so `None` is returned by default.

Comment: Yes I understand but this code looks fine here no?
```
def get_tick():   
    resp = s.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/case')
    if resp.ok:
        case = resp.json()
        return case['tick'], case['status']
```

Comment: `resp.ok` seems to be False so default return value of None. Use print() to check its value or provide `else` expression.

Comment: I get this when I do so:
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: Then presumably the Traceback is showing something useful. You need to debug get_tick to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_tick` function must be evaluating `resp.ok` as False, so your  `return case['tick'], case['status']` is not being executed. This means that your function will execute just a `return` instead. Python does this automatically for us and, when it does, it always returns None. So your function (from Python's point of view) actually says this:

```
def get_tick():   
    resp = s.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/case')
    if resp.ok:
        case = resp.json()
        return case['tick'], case['status']
    return
```

Which effectively says: if resp.ok has a truthy value then return a tuple of `tick` and `status` values, else return None ("else" in an English language sense here, not a Python keyword sense) coming from the fact that the function finishes (no more code) with no explicit return value (as there's no return at all), so Python just returns `None`).

So you need to account for a `resp` that did not return data. e.g. (most simple fix in this scenario):

```
def get_tick():   
        resp = s.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/case')
        if resp.ok:
            case = resp.json()
            return case['tick'], case['status']
        return None, None  # Your main function is expecting a tuple of two elements returned
```

and then in `main`:

```
def main():
tick, status = get_tick()
if tick is not None:
    ticker_list = ['UB','GEM','ETF']
    market_prices = np.array([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
    market_prices = market_prices.reshape(3,2)
else:
    # Handle failure here
```

There are other ways to handle this of course which may suit the rest of your program better. This way is mostly for explanation/demonstration purposes (although it's still fine to use as-is).